# In WireGuard on a sending peer, how is packet sent from the `wg0` interface to the UDP port?

Tags: networking, wireguard, packets

I'm trying to understand, once a packet reaches the WireGuard interface (`wg0`) how is it sent to the UDP port from where it can be sent to the receiving peer.

I was reading the WireGuard whitepaper and it says

> The interface itself has a private key and a UDP port on which it listens (more on that later), followed by a list of peers

I have only an elementary understanding of networking but I thought processes listen on ports so what does it mean for a network interface to listen on a UDP port?

If there is some way for a network interface to listen to a port, then on the receiving peer, the packet can likewise be received on the WireGuard interface from the UDP port. Is this a correct understanding?

Answer (score 1):

WireGuard does create an UDP socket and binds it to an address with special kernel functions: [`sock_create_kern`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/net/socket.c#L1473) and [`kernel_bind`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/net/socket.c#L3513).

Here is WireGuard's [source code](https://github.com/WireGuard/wireguard-) for creating the IPv4 socket. There is a similar code for the IPv6 socket.

WireGuard binds the socket to an UDP tunnel with the `setup_upd_tunnel` call as well.